# Why my database table is not getting updated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I used the correct command to update my database table

```
$result_col ="UPDATE `try`.`5` SET `D` = '$value' WHERE `5`.`A` = '$filenames[$index]' ;";
```

It works if i write in phpmyadmin to update the database table using the above command.

But it doesnot work in my code, though when i echo the command it prints correct values

```
UPDATE Store SET D='SUN: 2.495' WHERE `Index` = 'Hi35'
UPDATE Store SET D='SUN: 1.416' WHERE `Index` = 'He_41'
```

And it doesnot show any error or warnings , i also used this `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

What could be the possible reasons?

```
I checked Database link, It works
I checked the code, NO error reports or warnings
I pasted the command in phpamyadmin, the command works
I used mysqli instead of mysql, still the same problem
```

I did so many trials but still why the command doesnot work in the code?

Any idea??

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Please show more code, the way you build the query

Comment: make it \`Store\` as "Store" is a reserved word

Comment: get anything from `mysql_error`

Comment: The 1st query and the displayed 2 lines are not the same why's that ?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO this is your own code from the [pevious question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581649/two-arrays-in-an-mysqli-update-query), I believe

Comment: maybe 0 rows affected, no idea without more nfo

Comment: Why aren't you using `mysqli` with `bind_param` to set your SQL values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked! there were spaces in the array $filenames, which  was ignored in phpmyadmin, that is why the query worked in phpmyadmin and not in the php script...

Answer (score -2):

Take the semicolon ';' out of your query string.

Comment: You're down voting but it's straight from the manual - http://us3.php.net/mysql_query
"The query string should not end with a semicolon."